# Aptana Debugger incompatible with Firefox 9.0.1 - what to do?

Tags: debugging, firefox, aptana, incompatibility

When I try to start Debug in Aptana 3, the Aptana main page isn't loaded, and  I only receive a sockets error message.

Firefox 9.0.1 reports that the Aptana Debugger is incompatible with this version, and Aptana Debugger Addon tells me that it can only use the older Firebug version up to 1.8. Uninstalling Firebug 1.9 and installing 1.8 leads to the messsage that the Aptane Debugger 1.7 (of Aptana Studio 3) cannot be used in the latest Firefox release.

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: Use an old version of Eclipse with an [old Aptana plugin](http://www.freshports.org/java/eclipse-aptana/)

Answer (score 0):

Use an old version of Eclipse with an old Aptana plugin, such as:

- [eclipse-aptana 1.2.2.024747_2](http://www.freshports.org/java/eclipse-aptana/)
- [eclipse-aptana-radrails 1.2.1.23268_3](http://www.freshports.org/java/eclipse-aptana-radrails/)